# Cannot read property 'string' of undefined Trying to understand React Native Native Modules via react-native-create-bridge

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-native-module

I'm currently attempting to do the Ios version of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrIIPNEjQfs) tutorial.
The tutorial is brief introduction to using native modudles in react-native via react-native-create-bridge

I should see a simple blue box under the text.  However, I'm getting the error 'Cannot ready property 'string' of undefined. [image] After examining the line in question AND removing the .string portion.  The page now renders, however, without the expected blue box.

This is what ThirdSquareNativeView.js looks like

```
//  Created by react-native-create-bridge

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native'

const ThirdSquare = requireNativeComponent('ThirdSquare', ThirdSquareView)

export default class ThirdSquareView extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('this this working?');
  }
  render() {
    return <ThirdSquare {...this.props} />
  }
}

ThirdSquareView.propTypes = {
  exampleProp: React.PropTypes.string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install and import `prop-types`.It is no longer a part of React.

```
npm install prop-types --save
```

And then use as

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Your code will be something like

```
ThirdSquareView.propTypes = {
  exampleProp: PropTypes.string
}
```